# Help with synchronization from a unit test in C#

Tags: c#, synchronization

I'm testing a class that wraps BackgroundWorker to perform an operation away from the UI thread in my application.

The test below fails if Timeout is exceeded and passes if progressEventCount reaches the expected number of events before then.

My question is about synchronization.  asyncExecutor.Progressed is fired from the Thread Pool thread that BackgroundWorker is using and the test thread reads it back in the while loop.

Am I using lock correctly?

```
    [Test]
    [Timeout(1250)]
    public void Execute()
    {
        var locker = new object();
        const int numberOfEvents = 10;
        const int frequencyOfEvents = 100;
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        int progressEventCount = 0;

        IGradualOperation tester = new TestGradualOperation(numberOfEvents, frequencyOfEvents);

        var asyncExecutor = new AsynchronousOperationExecutor();

        asyncExecutor.Progressed += (s, e) => { lock (locker) progressEventCount++; };

        asyncExecutor.Execute(tester);

        while (true)
        {
            int count;
            lock (locker)
            {
                count = progressEventCount;
            }
            if (count < numberOfEvents) continue;
            Assert.Pass("Succeeded after {0} milliseconds", (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }


//  Implementation
public class AsynchronousOperationExecutor
{
    public void Execute(IGradualOperation gradualOperation)
    {
        var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker {WorkerReportsProgress = true};

        backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerDoWork;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(gradualOperation);
    }

    private void BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myArgs = e.UserState as ProgressEventArgs;
        OnProgressed(myArgs);
    }

    static void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var workerThis = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        var operation = e.Argument as IGradualOperation;

        if (workerThis == null || operation == null) return;

        operation.Progressed += (s, e1) => workerThis.ReportProgress((int)e1.Percentage, e1);

        operation.Run();
    }

    private void OnProgressed(ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Progressed != null)
            Progressed(this, e);
    }

    public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> Progressed;
}


//   Test Helper Class
public class TestGradualOperation : IGradualOperation
{
    private readonly int _numberOfEvents;
    private readonly int _frequencyMilliseconds;

    public TestGradualOperation(int numberOfEvents, int frequencyMilliseconds)
    {
        _numberOfEvents = numberOfEvents;
        _frequencyMilliseconds = frequencyMilliseconds;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfEvents; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(_frequencyMilliseconds);
            OnProgressed(new ProgressEventArgs(i, _numberOfEvents));
        }
    }

    private void OnProgressed(ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Progressed != null)
            Progressed(this, e);            
    }

    public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> Progressed;
}
```

Comment: What is the result of running the code?

Comment: Success: Succeeded after ~1045 milliseconds.

Comment: Looks okay.  Not sure why you'd consider re-inventing BGW.  Your main thread is burning 100% core.

Comment: The use of lock looks correct, but its not the most efficient way of doing that synchronization. You could use Interlocked.Increment/Read for simple operations on ints. Also the if (count<numberOfEvents) continue; is very inefficient as Hans mentioned. It should sleep or use some kind of signalling so thats its not just constantly locking and then doing an if check.

Comment: My uncertainty is as to whether the second lock is necessary since the only thread that runs through that part of the code is the test thread. I thought I might want to make sure the assignment **count = progressEventCount** was consistent since other threads may change **progressEventCount** in the background.  If someone could provide an answer showing how to lock correctly and wait efficiently then I can accept it with a nice big green tick, many thanks all.

Comment: @Hans it's not that I want to re-invent BackgroundWorker, it's just that I want to wrap it in a more easily testable interface.  It also means I can change the implementation without affecting clients if I want to.

Comment: @BrandonAGr I wasn't bothered by the inefficiency since the test will only run for a short time before the time-out, but should I be more concerned?  I'm self taught and performance isn't an area I've delved into in detail yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this revision is an improvement, blocking the test thread and signalling with an AutoResetEvent.  Not winning any brownie points for test readability though.

```
    [Test]
    [Timeout(1250)]
    public void Execute()
    {
        var locker = new object();
        EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);// <--
        const int numberOfEvents = 10;
        const int frequencyOfEvents = 100;
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        int progressEventCount = 0;

        IGradualOperation tester = new TestGradualOperation(numberOfEvents, frequencyOfEvents);

        var asyncExecutor = new AsynchronousOperationExecutor();

        asyncExecutor.Progressed += (s, e) =>
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                progressEventCount++;
                waitHandle.Set();// <--
            }
        };

        asyncExecutor.Execute(tester);

        while (true)
        {
            waitHandle.WaitOne();// <--
            if (progressEventCount < numberOfEvents) continue;
            Assert.Pass("Succeeded after {0} milliseconds", (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```